# How to create a vector list in a dataframe where there is repetition of values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

|  | pathways | genes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | REACTOME_2_LTR_CIRCLE_FORMATION | ENSG00000175334 |
| 2 | REACTOME_A_TETRASACCHARIDE_LINKER_SEQUENCE_IS_REQUIRED_FOR_GAG_SYNTHESIS | ENSG00000109956 |
| 3 | REACTOME_ABC_FAMILY_PROTEINS_MEDIATED_TRANSPORT | ENSG00000072849 |
| 5 | REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE | ENSG00000196230 |
| 12 | REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE | ENSG00000101162 |
| 13 | REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE | ENSG00000137267 |

I would like to create a vector `c()` of all the pathways for a sigle gene.
I tried with `group_by()` in dplyr but it is not working.

```
sub_pathway=sub_path%>%
  group_by(genes)%>%
  summarise(n())
```

It gives me just the count. If i do only `summarise()`, it gives me only the gene column list.
I also try a loop but it is turning until yesterday.

```
structure(list(pathways = c("REACTOME_2_LTR_CIRCLE_FORMATION", "REACTOME_A_TETRASACCHARIDE_LINKER_SEQUENCE_IS_REQUIRED_FOR_GAG_SYNTHESIS", "REACTOME_ABC_FAMILY_PROTEINS_MEDIATED_TRANSPORT", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE"), genes = c("ENSG00000175334", "ENSG00000109956", "ENSG00000072849", "ENSG00000196230", "ENSG00000101162", "ENSG00000137267")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide example data e.g. using `dput(head(df))`

Comment: pathways           genes
1                 REACTOME_2_LTR_CIRCLE_FORMATION ENSG00000175334
2  REACTOME_A_TETRASACCHARIDE_LINKER_SEQUENCE  ENSG00000109956
3     REACTOME_ABC_FAMILY_PROTEINS_MEDIATED_TRANSPORT ENSG00000072849
5                                                       REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE ENSG00000196230
12                                                      REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE ENSG00000101162
13                                                      REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE ENSG00000137267

Comment: We can not infer the column names based on this comment. Line breaks are important

Comment: @Lamine What you’ve posted isn’t the output from `dput`.

Comment: Hi @KonradRudolph the dput is giving me to,much variable, i can not add them in the comment. It is the output of ``head()``

Comment: @Lamine Add the output *to the question* (you can edit your question), not in a comment.

Comment: @KonradRudolph i add it

Comment: @danlooo, i add the output

Comment: Why there is no column gene but only pathways and  .Label ?

Comment: @Lamine What you’ve posted is *incomplete*, it doesn’t correspond to a data.frame. The issue is probably that your data contains very large factor vectors, which got truncated. Could you please try posting the output of the following: `dput(head(\`[<-\`(sub_path, , value = sapply(sub_path, as.character))))`. (you need to carefully copy and paste this *exact* code).

Comment: There is a column gene, ensembl gene. I just edit again my post so normally you can see it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok but i think there is a mistake in your code. You can checkit it please

Comment: @KonradRudolph structure(list(pathways = c("REACTOME_2_LTR_CIRCLE_FORMATION", 
"REACTOME_A_TETRASACCHARIDE_LINKER_SEQUENCE_IS_REQUIRED_FOR_GAG_SYNTHESIS", 
"REACTOME_ABC_FAMILY_PROTEINS_MEDIATED_TRANSPORT", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", 
"REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE", "REACTOME_CELL_CYCLE"), genes = c("ENSG00000175334", 
"ENSG00000109956", "ENSG00000072849", "ENSG00000196230", "ENSG00000101162", 
"ENSG00000137267")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is in a data.frame, you *cannot* put all pathways for a gene into a single vector. In fact, each column in the table *is* a vector, and vectors in R are flat: they cannot be nested.

However, you can use *list* columns: lists are R’s way of nesting structures. Therefore, the following works:

```
sub_pathway = sub_path %>%
    group_by(genes) %>%
    summarise(pathways = list(pathways))
```

The result is a table with one row per gene, and the `pathways` column is a list with, for each row, one vector of pathways.

Unfortunately, R doesn’t make it very easy to work with list columns, so the resulting data might not be very easy to work with. For example, if you want to output the data it might be more convenient to merge the pathways into a character per gene:

```
sub_path %>%
    group_by(genes) %>%
    summarise(pathways = paste(pathways, collapse = ', '))
#   genes           pathways
#   <chr>           <chr>
# 1 ENSG00000000419 REACTOME_DISEASES_ASSOCIATED_WITH_GLYCOSYLATION_PRECURSOR_BIOSYNTHESIS…
# 2 ENSG00000000938 REACTOME_FCGAMMA_RECEPTOR_FCGR_DEPENDENT_PHAGOCYTOSIS, REACTOME_FCGR_A…
```

What’s more convenient depends on what you need to do with the data afterwards.